# Parsing a huge HTML stream with Jsoup

Tags: jsoup

Can anyone offer a pointer or advice as to how I would tackle parsing an extremely large HTML stream/file.  For instance I have a table with about 270,000 rows, I would like to bring it into my app about 20k at a time.  The jsoup parse method allows for fragments of HTML, but it is unclear to me as to what may be the most efficient and cleanest way to read XXX bytes representing this fragment.

Any help most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If it's XHTML, and you don't need to keep the whole thing in memory at once, a better bet might be to use a SAX parser and pick off the data you need using start and end tag events.

Another thought might be a StAX parser.